# Optional parameters in explicitly implemented interfaces

Tags: c#, optional-parameters, explicit-interface

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Foo(bool flag = true);
}

public class Test : IFoo
{
    void IFoo.Foo(bool flag = true) //here compiler generates a warning
    {

    }
}
```

The warning says that the given default value will be ignored as it is used in the context which does not allow it.

Why are optional parameters not allowed for explicitly implemented interfaces?

Comment: Why you need to override the default parameter that specified in IFoo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly implemented interface methods are always *called* with a target whose compile-time type is the interface, not an specific implementation. The compiler looks at the optional parameters declare by the method it "knows" it's invoking. How would you expect it to know to take the parameters from `Test.Foo` when it only knows of the target expression as type `IFoo`?

```
IFoo x = new Test();
x.Foo(); // How would the compiler know to look at the Test.Foo declaration here?
```

Comment: I didn't think it tryed to override it. I thought the implementation had to be declared similar to the interface declaration, word for word...I even didn't mean to override it. Now I see, this assumption  was absolutely wrong...Now that warning does make sense.

Comment: You're not really "overriding" as such - you're *implementing*.

Comment: That's why I thought, compiler wouldn't think, I wanted to change the default value for the parameter

Answer (score 0):

I would use method overloading.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Foo(bool flag);
    void Foo();
}

public class Test : IFoo
{
    void Foo() {
        this.Foo(true);
    }

    void Foo(bool flag) {
         // Your stuff here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops... :D I'll change my answer.